# How do I extract multiple dataframes based on criteria in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Given the dataframe and list below -

```
dfx = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,10))
dfx.columns = ['id1', 'id2', 'maars1', 'maars2', 'maars3', 'maars4', 'crsc1', 'crsc2', 'crsc3', 'crsc4']

lst = ['maars', 'crsc']
```

How do I create 2 dataframes. The first one will be called "df_maars" and will have the following columns, "id1, id2, maars1, maars2, maars3, maars4.

The second dataframe will be called "df_crsc" and will have the following columns, "id1, id2, crsc1, crsc2, crsc3, crsc4.

Note - my dataframe and list contain way more variables than "maars" and "crsc" And each variable has about 14 columns.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the following:

```
df_maars = dfx[['id1', 'id2', 'maars1', 'maars2', 'maars3', 'maars4']].copy()

df_crsc = dfx[['id1', 'id2', 'crsc1', 'crsc2', 'crsc3', 'crsc4']].copy()
```

Comment: nit: maybe double check if it creates a reference to the columns or clones/copies. It's pretty tricky when you modify one and the other changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df_ids = dfx.loc[:, 'id1':'id2']
df_maars = df_ids.join(dfx.loc[:, 'maars1':'maars4'])
df_crsc = df_ids.join(dfx.loc[:, 'crsc1':'crsc4'])
```